# Python SimPy: yield env.timeout not working

Tags: python, simpy

I'm just getting started with SimPy so maybe I'm missing something major here. I have a very simple Process which I want to just increment a number once per second.

```
class Simulation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        thing = Thing()
        p = self.env.process(thing.go(self.env))
        self.env.run()

simulation = Simulation()
```

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def go(self,env):
        while True:
            self.x = self.x + 1
            print("Current value: {}".format(self.x))
            yield env.timeout(1)
```

The timeout seems to be getting ignored here. It doesn't matter what value I pass as the delay, or whether I include the line at all, x increases at the same rate(over 1 million within seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing real-time with sim-time.  Have your print statement include the current time (env.now).  You should get something like this:

```
Current value: 2 , time now: 0
Current value: 3 , time now: 1
Current value: 4 , time now: 2
Current value: 5 , time now: 3
:
```

So, you can see the simulation clock is incrementing as is should; the simulation is just really fast.  If you want to run in real time, don't use simpy.environment().  Instead, use simpy.rt.RealTimeEnvironment().
See here for more details: 
https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/real-time-simulations.html